# Vue bootstrap datepicker can't back to today

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, datetimepicker

I'm using the **vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker**

https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker

and I have a big issue: when I set tomorrow as date I can't go back to today. I think it is a problem with type past from moment.js but I'm not sure

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <date-picker name="date" v-model="date" :config="config"></date-picker>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and script

```
Vue.component('date-picker', VueBootstrapDatetimePicker.default);
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: null,
    config: {
      // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      useCurrent: true,
      minDate: moment(),
      showClear: true,
      showClose: true,
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you have that problem without `minDate: moment(),` in the config?

Comment: no, if i take off minDate: moment() works, but i need set minDate

Comment: In that case can you try to call a proper format on `moment()` in case it is not outputting correctly.

Comment: if I use `minDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');` this bug of back today solve but generate another bug when I use two elemets like in this case https://jsfiddle.net/guifreire/su5wz3jc/